# Using std::stringstream to convert boost::int64_t large number to string.

Tags: c++, ios

See the following code, debug and show convert is successful on both iPhone simulator and device (4S), but I wonder how does it work? See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ostream/operator%3C%3C/, no overload function for boost::int64_t.

Any risk if I use this function to convert any arbitrary boost::int64_t type? Thanks in advance.

```
std::stringstream mySS;
boost::int64_t large = 4294967296889977;
mySS<<large;
std::string str = mySS.str();
```

Comment: Well of course the language doesn't come with it's own operator for a boost type. That's why we can overload them.

Comment: The reason it works is that `boost:int64_t` is really a typedef to a built-in type (typically `std::int64_t` defined in cstdint or something like that), so it probably ends up being the same as `long long` (or similar, depending on the platform), and of course there is an overload of `stringstream::operator<<` for that.

Comment: @jogojapan, Huh, I guess that makes a lot of sense, but I didn't know that. Even if it weren't boost can still overload the operator for it. Also, the cplusplus list is incomplete. There are overloads for `long long` and `unsigned long long` not mentioned there.

Comment: @chris True -- then again, overloading the operator if `boost::int64_t` happens to be same as a built-in type means you'll get an ambiguous-overload error unless you make the overload somehow conditional. Plus, if `boost:int64_t` is really _not_ identical to a built-in type, your overloaded operator will either involve very complex code, or call `boost::lexical_cast` to perform the conversion. In that cast it may be better to simply call `boost::lexical_cast` directly.

Comment: @jogojapan, Yes, I was commenting as if it was a different type for sure, and my point was that if it is, the language allows you to do it your way.

Comment: Thanks you guys. If not overloaded, compiler warnings or errors will appear. Now not see it, seems C++ library has done it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it works is that `boost:int64_t` is really a typedef to a built-in type (typically `std::int64_t` defined in `cstdint` or something like that), so it probably ends up being the same as `long long` (or similar, depending on the platform). Of course there is an overload of `stringstream::operator<<` for that.

For the exact definition, best see [`boost/cstdint.hpp`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/cstdint.hpp) (1.51 version).

It is probably a relatively safe bet to assume that this will generally work on all major platforms. But I doubt anyone will be able to give a guarantee for that.

If the purpose of your using `std::stringstream` is to convert between integers and strings, the safest thing you can do is simply to use Boost's own way of converting: [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html) (1.51 version). Here is how it's done:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/cstdint.hpp>
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>

int main()
{
  boost::int64_t i = 12;
  std::string    s = boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(i);

  std::cout << s << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks you guy, your provided method is much safer.